# Is it possible to change the element id separator in JSF?

Tags: java, html, jsf, facelets

For example, the following snippet:

```
<h:form id="levelone">
    <h:inputText id="leveltwo" value="Test" />
</h:form>
```

generates the following markup:

```
<form id="levelone" name="levelone" method="post" action="/test/testPage.html" 
      enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
   <input id="levelone:leveltwo" type="text" name="levelone:leveltwo" 
          value="Test" />
</form>
```

**Is it possible to change the automatically generated ids to use a different separator than colon?**

For example, I'd like to change

```
levelone:leveltwo
```

to

```
levelone-leveltwo
```

## Background

We're using the [Mojo](http://blastmojo.com/) JavaScript application framework in our webapp, and it doesn't seem to like the colons in the id's.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not possible in JSF 1.x, but since JSF 2.x you can define it in `web.xml` as `init-param` of `javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR`.

That said, I guess that you just wanted to change it because you'd like to get your CSS to work, is it? The colon `:` is namely a special character in CSS identifiers, it represents a pseudo selector. If this reason is true for you, then it might be good to know that you can escape special characters in CSS the usual way by `\`.

Thus, e.g.

```
#levelone\:leveltwo {
    color: blue;
}
```

ought to work for normal browsers (for IE6/7 you need `#levelone\3A leveltwo` instead).

The same applies when you intend to use it with [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or any other JavaScript framework which selects elements with help of [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/):

```
var leveltwo = $('#levelone\\:leveltwo');
```

Alternatively, you can also just give it a `styleClass` which you in turn can correlate with a CSS class. Thus, e.g.

```
<h:inputText styleClass="myinput" />
```

which generates

```
<input type="text" class="myinput" />
```

can be styled with

```
.myinput {
    color: blue;
}
```

#### See also

- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery)
- [How to use JSF generated HTML element ID with colon ":" in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-in-css-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

In older versions, no it is not possible. It is a hard coded constant. In 2.0, you can change it. See [this blog post](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html#theseparatorcharacter).

Comment: Isn't 2.0 a current version? It was already final for more than half a year.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what I was thinking. I'm stuck on an old version, maybe that's why. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

[Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/index.html) has extended components, like `<t:inputText>` which have the `forceId` attribute. There you'll have to set it as `<t:inputText forceId="levelone-leveltwo" />` - i.e. you won't be able to use the automatic generated container(s) name.

I'd advise against such a thing - I don't see a valid reason why the `:` should be changed to `-`