# custom .ui-state-active -style for selectManyButton

Tags: css, primefaces

I want to add a custom style to a selectManyButton in primefaces 5.1. The style I want to change is bound to the .ui-state-active class. When I change this class, I get my custom style for the selectManyButton, but all other elements which refer to this styleclass, changed, too. How can I make that just one certain element change to the defined style?

```
<p:selectManyButton  value="#{projektCriteriaBean.selectedOptions}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{projektCriteriaBean.yearSelection}"  />
        <p:ajax listener="#{projektCriteriaBean.changeDate}"  update=":form:startDate,:form:endDate" />
    </p:selectManyButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an `id` or `styleClass` for your button.

```
<h:form id="my_form">
    <p:selectManyButton id="my_unique_selector" styleClass="generic-selector"
            value="#{projektCriteriaBean.selectedOptions}">
        <!--  ... -->
    </p:selectManyButton>
</h:form>
```

The difference between `id` and `class` is a HTML matter, that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/544052/1341535).

I've included the `h:form` because the parent naming containers affect the resulting client id. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8644762/1341535).

Now you can stylize your button by class:

```
.generic-selector .ui-state-active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Or by id:

```
#my_form\:my_unique_selector .ui-state-active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The colon is a JSF naming container default separator char. It needs to be escaped with a backslash, because `:` has a special meaning in CSS. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146524/1341535).

Comment: Great, it works ! Many thanks for the fast and qualified answer. I t saves my sunday evening.