# What does a colon mean within an HTML id attribute?

Tags: html, css, tags

I have seen an HTML code like this for the ID attribute:

```
id="t1:c3"
```

Can someone explain this to me? What is the purpose of the colon (`:`)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Colons are allowed inside ID attributes, but hold no special significance.  It's not really advisable to use them because they can sometimes cause problems, such as when used with jQuery or CSS, where the colon has special meaning as a pseudo-selector.

Comment: so you mean this will not be advisable also for css?

Comment: That's right, because in CSS the colon is used for pseudo-selectors, like `#div.button:hover`

Comment: I agree with cxfx, but if there is very big need to use colons, then you can escape it on css like `#t1\:c3 { rules ;}`

Answer (score 6):

If the HTML is generated with Java ServerFaces this usually produces such IDs, i.e. if the form has the ID *form1* and the element has the ID *firstName* this results in an ID `form1:firstName` if the element is on top level, if there are several ones created in a loop they look like `form1:1:firstName`, `form1:2:firstName`, …

This framework behaviour cannot be changed.

Comment: For JSF, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7928290/1599699 The exact ID must be used, so e.g. if you put `id="blah"` in your code, but that element is within an `<h:form id="form">`, well, form is a `NamingContainer` element and so the actual ID will be `form:blah` in the raw output HTML. Thus, you'll have to specify `form:blah` in your custom CSS styling.

Comment: Note also that when using a colon in CSS styling, you need to use `\:` instead of `:` for IE 8 - IE 11 or `\3A` instead of `:` for IE 6 - IE 7 (or for any version). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector#comment80053896_122266

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above I have discovered that Omniture uses colons to help define classes related to the layout.