# Why jQuery function returns null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form:

```
<form action="javascript:;" class="iceFrm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="frmMainMenu" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
.....
</form>
```

I do not understand why this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#frmMainMenu").$("#menuPopupAP").$("#menuItem0").$("#out").css('padding','0 0 0 29px');
});
</script>
```

says:

> `$("#frmMainMenu")` is null

in Firebug.

**UPDATE:**
This is the html element (from the above form) I want to change the padding on:

```
<span id="frmMainMenu:menuPopupAP:menuItem0:out" class="iceOutTxt iceMnuItmLabel graMenuPopupMenuItemLabel">My Applications</span>
```

Update 2:

I've forgot to mention that this span is within a menu, so basically it's hidden normally and displayed only when hovering on some div... Does jQuery finds it even if it's not displayed?

Do you know why?

Comment: Can you post the entire form?

Comment: The result of `$(...)` does not have another property `$(...)`.

Comment: `$("#frmMainMenu").$("#menuPopupAP").$("#menuItem0").$("#out")` is not correct.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I've updated my post, maybe the way I try to find this elements is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#frmMainMenu:menuPopupAP:menuItem0:out').css('padding','0 0 0 29px');
```

```
$('span[id="frmMainMenu:menuPopupAP:menuItem0:out"]').css('padding','0 0 0 29px');
```

You need to use the `[id="value"]` syntax, because in a jQuery selector the `:` can be used as a selector, so it doesn't realize that the IDs can contain them.

Comment: Well, very strange it still gives me null...please note that the above id is taken from Firebogu so basically it's the composed id of all parent components...

Comment: @Cristian: What do you mean by "composed id"?

Comment: I mean that it takes the ids of all parents and shown the results with : between ids...

Comment: @Cristian: I didn't know Firebug did that.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked and I also needed to replace $ with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly why you're getting the null error, but if your intent is to apply that style to those four specific elements the syntax should be:

```
$("#frmMainMenu, #menuPopupAP, #menuItem0, #out").css('padding','0 0 0 29px');
```

If (and I can't tell as we've been giving an insufficient markup sample) those four elements are successive nodes in a hierarchy (i.e. `#out` is a child of `#menuItem` is a child of `#menuPopupAp` is a child of `#frmMainMnenu`) then remove the commas between them.

**EDIT** colons in an id?   That'll cause problems with jQuery selectors.  Try using an underscore instead?

Comment: IDs *can* contain colons, it's valid, but jQuery can't select IDs with colons like that, because the `:` is read as a selector.  You need to do `[id="value"]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** after your question update:

```
$('#frmMainMenu\3AmenuPopupAP\3AmenuItem0\3Aout').css('padding','0 0 0 29px');
```

You cant use the `:` in your selector but you can use the hexadecimal equivalent - `\3A`

There are few other workarounds on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector).

---

Are your trying to search the children of `frmMainMenu`? try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#frmMainMenu").find("#menuPopupAP")
                             .find("#menuItem0")
                             .find("#out")
                             .css('padding','0 0 0 29px');
});
```

Comment: `$('#frmMainMenu:menuPopupAP:menuItem0:out')` doesn't actually work, because jQuery uses the `:` as a selector.

Comment: @Rocket - yes, I realised that. Thanks. Have update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that - it's one of the children that is null. You need to change your script to something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#frmMainMenu #menuPopupAP #menuItem0 #out").css('padding','0 0 0 29px');
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you don't mean to use # each time (otherwise you could just use #out, but it sounds like it should be something like

$("#frmMainMenu .menuPopupAP .menuItem0 .out").css(...

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what do you need to accomplish?
from your selector, I think you are taking a hard selector approach to interact with your DOM.