# Get all the content within <style> tag in a html file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html file and some css written inside style tag. I have requirement to extract text inside this tag. eg:

```
<style>
    html,body {
        margin: 0px;
        width:100%;
    }
    .center-text {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

I need to extract values inside this tag in a string using jquery. I tried several posts but couldn't get any appropriate answer.

Comment: i tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189252/get-style-tag-content-with-jquery as well but it doesn't work for me. I am checking in updated chrome version.

Comment: Thats weird requirement. Whats the purpose ?

Comment: @YoYo I need to store this css in db.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this?

```
$("#YourDiv").html($("style").html())
```

this will get css code as string and put it into div
if you need to save it to db you can send it via ajax to your server