# Using lxml.html's cssselect to select element with colon in ID attribute

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

I have an element in a page that looks like this:

```
<a id="cid-694094:Comment:188384" name="694094:Comment:188384"></a>
```

If you do `document.cssselect("#cid-694094:Comment:188384")` you will get:

> lxml.cssselect.ExpressionError: The psuedo-class Symbol(u'Comment', 12) is unknown

The solution for that is handled in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector) (the person was using Java).

However, when I try that in Python as such:

```
document.cssselect(r"#cid-694094\:Comment\:188384")
```

I get:

> lxml.cssselect.SelectorSyntaxError: Bad symbol 'cid-694094\': 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode byte 0x5c in position 10: \ at end of string at [Token(u'#', 0)] -> None

The reason for that and a proposed solution can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file). If I understand it correctly I should be doing:

```
document.cssselect(r"#cid-694094\\:Comment\\:188384")
```

But this still doesn't work. Instead I once again get:

> lxml.cssselect.ExpressionError: The psuedo-class Symbol(u'Comment\', 14) is unknown

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Try it yourself using:

```
import lxml.html
document = lxml.html.fromstring(
    '<a id="cid-694094:Comment:188384" name="694094:Comment:188384"></a>'
)
document.cssselect(r"#cid-694094\:Comment\:188384")
```

Comment: That's odd, I swear StackOverflow is collapsing backward slashes in the last exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't `:` [not allowed in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names) for id or class?

Here is a work-around:

```
document.xpath('//a[@id="cid-694094:Comment:188384"]')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is or is not allowed. But the question I linked to earlier says you can escape the colon in your selector and it should work. Your propose a pretty good work around, but, I assume it would be slower than an actual CSS selector by ID? Because this will have to check all A element right? Maybe I can use getElementById...

Comment: Ah, with that link, now I'm pretty sure that it is not allowed. The HTML isn't under my control though, I just scrape it, so I'll just have to work around it.

Comment: Actually csselector is converted to xpath with `lxml.cssselect.css_to_xpath()`

Comment: Very enlightening! It turns out your work-around is almost exactly what cssselect("#id") would do. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to source code: https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/cssselect.py :)

Answer (score 1):

`:` is normally not allowed in ID selectors, and this is indeed the correct way to escape it:

```
document.cssselect(r"#cid-694094\:Comment\:188384")
```

However the selector parser in was really broken until recently. (It did not really implement backslash-escapes.) I fixed this in cssselect 0.7 which is now an independent project, extracted from lxml.

http://packages.python.org/cssselect/

The "new" way to use it is a bit more verbose:

```
import cssselect
document.xpath(cssselect.HTMLTranslator().css_to_xpath('#cid-694094\:Comment\:188384'))
```

lxml 2.4 (not released yet) will use the new cssselect so the simpler syntax will work too.