# how to remove upload cancel button from <p:fileUpload>

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In my JSF 2.0 - Primefaces application I am using  I DO NOT want to have

1. progress bar
2. upload button
3. cancel button
   which shows up adjacent to the selected image(once the image is selected)

Another issue is the 'fileLimit' I want to set it to 1 but when I do that it says invalid attribute.

Here is my code:

```
<p:fileUpload id="related_image" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"  
        mode="advance"  
        auto="false" 
        showButtons="false"
        sizeLimit="100000"
        fileLimit ="1"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
        style="width: 310px"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically  all you have to do is to assign find out the right *css* selectors and set them with `display:none;` (put them in your .css file and include it with `<h:outputStylesheet`)

in general (in css you need to escape the *colon* with `\3a` [Handling a colon in an element ID in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/656463/617373) , while in jquery you should use `\\:`)

```
#some_prefix_id\3a your_file_upload_component_id .someClass{
    display:none;
}
```

> where the some_prefix_id might be some form id or some naming
>   container id ,

or (sometimes there is no prefix before *your_file_upload_component_id* )

```
#your_file_upload_component_id .someClass{
    display:none;
}
```

Although , INMO , best approach would be assigning an id to your form and using this selector in css :

```
#your_form_id .someClass{
    display:none;
}
```

Now to the exact selectors...

so to remove the *upload button*

```
#related_image .start{
    display:none;
}
```

or if you want to do the same with jquery

```
$("#related_image .start").hide();
```

to remove the *cancel button which shows up adjacent to the selected image(once the image is selected)*

```
#related_image .cancel{
    display:none;
}
```

or if you want to do the same with jquery

```
$("#related_image .cancel").hide();
```

to remove progress bar

```
#related_image .progress{
    display:none;
}
```

or if you want to do the same with jquery

```
$("#related_image .progress").hide();
```

You can test the jquery approach on primefaces showcase if you want , just replace the `#related_image` with `#j_idt19\\:j_idt20`  for example `$("#j_idt19\\:j_idt20 .start").hide();`

---

There is no such attribute as `fileLimit` take a look at the [Tag fileUpload](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/fileUpload.html)

Comment: what will be the value of styleClass for <p:fileUpload>

Comment: no value at all... just place all the *css* code I posted above in your custom css file and include it in your xhtml page , thats all...

Comment: If I put 
.progress{
    display:none;
} this works but if I use
#related_image .progress{
    display:none;
} this doesnt work, any clue

Comment: work with your browser dev tools / firefox and inspect the id of your upload component , in showcase for example its something like `j_idt19:j_idt20` , that is the prefix of the css selectors...

Comment: id of p:fileupload is related_image

Comment: does `#related_image.progress{ display:none; }` without space works ? you could also assign id to a form that wraps the fileupload component and try `#yourFormID .progress{ display:none; }`

Comment: #yourFormID .progress{ display:none; } works thanks a million Daniel. Just want to check if you have answer for my second query the 'fileLimit' I want to set it to 1 but when I do that it says invalid attribute.

Comment: well primefaces user guide 3.3 has a mentioned about that. Do you know any other approach to restrict this to only 1 file allowed to be uploaded

Comment: its should be by default (`multiple="false"`) take a look at the showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf

Comment: (multiple="false") will not allow multiple files to be selected for upload in the file dialog in one shot but what I want it p:uploadfile component should allow only one file to be selected for upload.

Comment: Than you should use `auto="true"`