# Remove File Upload and Cancel Button from Primefaces p:fileUpload

Tags: css, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I would like to remove upload and cancel button from p:fileUpload. For Upload button I tried css like this (in different variations):

```
.ui-fileupload-upload button {
        display: none;
}
```

but it continues to be visible.

```
<button type="button"
    class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-state-disabled ui-fileupload-upload"
    disabled="disabled">
    <span
        class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-n"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Upload</span>
</button>
```

I saw this publication [a link] ([how to remove upload cancel button from <p:fileUpload>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652413/how-to-remove-upload-cancel-button-from-pfileupload)) and tried again different css but i did not manage to get rid of it. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to tell the PrimeFaces version used.

Comment: Primefaces, version 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### PrimeFaces 6.x or newer

Use at least these attributes:

```
<p:fileUpload ... auto="true" skinSimple="true" />
```

#### PrimeFaces 4.x / 5.x

You can only use CSS for this as they removed the `showButtons` attribute:

```css
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar .ui-fileupload-upload {
    display: none;
}
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar .ui-fileupload-cancel {
    display: none;
}
```

Beware of CSS ordering rules, see also [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

#### PrimeFaces 3.x or older

Use at least these attributes:

```
<p:fileUpload ... auto="true" showButtons="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar .ui-fileupload-upload {
    display: none;
}
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar .ui-fileupload-cancel {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Why is this better than the accepted and upvoted answer

Comment: The question asked was not about all the Buttons, but only on 'Upload' and 'Cancel' buttons.  "I would like to remove upload and cancel button from p:fileUpload. ...."

Comment: BalusC's answer asks to set showbuttons false. But there is no such attribute in case of primefaces 6. Your solutions worked fine.

Answer (score -2):

In angular, using `FileUploader` from `ng2-file-upload`, in `.html` :

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue let i = index">
    <td>
      <div *ngIf= "!uploader.queue[i].isUploaded">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" style="margin:2px" (click)="onSubmit(i,item,$event.target)" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
       </button>
      </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

In the `component.ts`

```
    public index:number ;
    public onFileSelected() {
      this.uploader.queue[this.index].isUploaded=false; // initializing uploaded to false
    }

    public onSubmit(index:number){
      this.uploadService.uploadFile(this.csvJsonData).subscribe((responseData)=>{
      this.onSubmitresponse = responseData ;
      if(this.onSubmitresponse.status==201){
        this.uploader.queue[index].progress = 100;
        this.toastrService.success('The File has been uploaded successfully !',this.onSubmitresponse.status,{positionClass:'toast-bottom-center'});

        this.uploader.queue[index].isUploaded=true;// will hide the upload button
      }
     else this.toastrService.error(this.onSubmitresponse.errorMessage,this.onSubmitresponse.status,{positionClass:'toast-bottom-center'});
    });

  }
```

Comment: This question is about PrimeFaces, not PrimeNG