# Hide upload button PrimeNG

Tags: angular, upload, primeng

I'm using file upload from PrimeNG : 
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload

For now, I have this [image]

But I would like to have only "Choose" and "Cancel" buttons.
[image]

So on primeNG website, they say to use `showUploadButton="false"`

But it's not working.

Refering to this post : 
[Remove File Upload and Cancel Button from Primefaces p:fileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418921/remove-file-upload-and-cancel-button-from-primefaces-pfileupload?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I tried :

```
<p-fileUpload ...  showButtons="false" showCancelButton="true"/>
```

then I tried

```
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar .ui-fileupload-upload {
    display: none;
}
```

**Nothing works.** 
Maybe it's because it was refering to another version.
I'm using version of primeNG 2.0.6 and angular 2.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution working for me was to hide it with css :

```
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar button:nth-child(2){
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: it's not working with latest version of primeNg.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v11-lts/#/fileupload

Answer (score 22):

You have to put the showUploadButton inside of a bracket for it to work.

```
<p-fileUpload [showUploadButton]="false"></p-fileUpload>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp17J.png)

EDIT: You need to get the latest version of PrimeNG to work with Angular 4. Since Angular launched their Angular 4, PrimeNG has also launched PrimeNG v4 to work with Angular 4

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to do like this:

```
<p:fileUpload ...  [showButtons]="false" [showCancelButton]="true"/>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Nop, i'm getting Can't bind to 'showButtons' since it isn't a known property of 'p-fileUpload'.

Comment: Mmm si it look your notnusing it proprlerly.. so double check how you import module ... or if it is really p:fileUpload

Comment: Aw right i'm using p-fileUpload. If I change it to p:fileUpload it says "namespace p is not bound". 
On their website it's p-fileUpload. What should I do ?

Comment: It look like you have not imported or installare it correctly.. try to cancel your npm modules reinstall it and look how to import correctly

Comment: I did it, it doesnt work. Morever, on their website it's written with p-fileUpload. 
Looks like on the version I'm using there is not all variables available.

Comment: How can I get old documentation of primeng ? I didn't find it

Answer (score 1):

To hide BUTTONBAR:

```
::ng-deep .p-fileupload .p-fileupload-buttonbar {
    display:none;
}
```

To hide CONTENT files:

```
::ng-deep .p-fileupload .p-fileupload-content {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `FileUploader` from `ng2-file-upload`, in `.html` :

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue let i = index">
    <td>
      <div *ngIf= "!uploader.queue[i].isUploaded">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" style="margin:2px" (click)="onSubmit(i,item,$event.target)" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
       </button>
      </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

In the `component.ts`

```
    public index:number ;
    public onFileSelected() {
      this.uploader.queue[this.index].isUploaded=false; // initializing uploaded to false
    }

    public onSubmit(index:number){
      this.uploadService.uploadFile(this.csvJsonData).subscribe((responseData)=>{
      this.onSubmitresponse = responseData ;
      if(this.onSubmitresponse.status==201){
        this.uploader.queue[index].progress = 100;
        this.toastrService.success('The File has been uploaded successfully !',this.onSubmitresponse.status,{positionClass:'toast-bottom-center'});

        this.uploader.queue[index].isUploaded=true;// will hide the upload button
      }
     else this.toastrService.error(this.onSubmitresponse.errorMessage,this.onSubmitresponse.status,{positionClass:'toast-bottom-center'});
    });

  }
```

Answer (score -2):

[showUploadButton]="false" [showCancelButton]="false"

Comment: This answer seem to propose a similar solution to thing that were already said. Also, without any comment about what this does, it is not really helpful.