# css style to the specific id is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, xhtml, primefaces

In my JSF 2 Primeface application I have following file upload component.

```
<p:fileUpload id="related_image" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"  
    mode="advance"  
    auto="false" 
    showButtons="false"
    sizeLimit="100000"
    fileLimit ="1"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
    style="width: 310px"/>
```

I want to remove progress bar from this component so I am doing

```
.progress {
display: none;
```

}

and this work but I want to remove the progress bar attached to this file upload component only and not from my entire application, so I tried

```
#related_image .progress{
display:none;
```

}

but this doesnt work, any clue guys?

Comment: CSS doesn't style a JSF component but the HTML output from the server. Please paste the HTML code received by a browser

Answer (score 2):

Your `<p:fileUpload>` component can have *prepended id*. View the generated HTML output after deploying and check for the actual id of the component. 
`<p:fileUpload>` is in some `form` (or in other wrapping component e.g. `<p:panel>`). Primefaces automatically add `forms` id to components inside this `form`. So the actual id of `<p:fileUpload>` probably looks like `id="formID:fileUpID"` and thats why it can't find *#fileUpID*.

**Note**: You can disable prepending ids by `prependId="false"` attribute.

**Note 2**: You can also try to specify `styleClass` for the `<p:fileUpload>`, which you can style in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

First, you got an extra space in

> `\#related_image .progress{`

the selector should be

`#related_image.progress{`

Second, if the `fileUpload` component really has prefixed id (as the Fallup suggests) you need to escape the colon from the id in the css selector - see e.g. [Handling a colon in an element ID in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector) for this.

Answer (score 0):

in general (in css you need to escape the *colon* with `\3a` [Handling a colon in an element ID in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/656463/617373) , while in jquery you should use `\\:`)

```
#some_prefix_id\3a your_file_upload_component_id .someClass{
    display:none;
}
```

> where the some_prefix_id might be some form id or some naming
>   container id ,

Although , INMO a better approach would be assigning an id to your form and using this selector in css :

```
#your_form_id .someClass{
    display:none;
}
```