# How to hide time-slots in "agendaWeek" View of FullCalendar/Primefaces <p:schedule>?

Tags: primefaces, hide, fullcalendar, schedule

Is it possible to hide the time-slots in "agendaWeek" View? I'm using Primefaces `<p:schedule>` which based on the FullCalendar. I only add AllDay-Events to this specfic schedule, so my client decided to hide the time-slots.

I hope there is a way.

Best regards

Comment: Any reason you can't use the month view?

Comment: I'm using the month view already. That's the problem, my client wants the "agendaWeek" View in case there are too many "all-day" events. So both views are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if that's what you mean

but to hide the first column in schedule try this css selector (remove `formID\3A` if you got `prependId = "false"` in your form that contains the scheduler )

```
#formID\3A scheduleID th.fc-agenda-axis{
    display:none
}
```

or run this js code (tested on primefaces showcase)

```
jQuery("th.fc-agenda-axis").hide()
```

---

**Update**

This is how to hide the time slots (what the OP was really looking for)

```
#formID\3A scheduleID table.fc-agenda-slots{
    display:none
}
```

Comment: Hm, it seems not working for me. I tried the first one. And the last one. But I'm sure I do something wrong. Where did you place the last solution in your anwser?

Comment: to rub the jquery  , just browse to http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf and click on week view, than in your chrome/ff open the deve tools with F12 and paste the code in console, havent tried the css selector , but if its not working , try `formID\:AscheduleID th.fc-agenda-axis` `\:` instead of `\3A` or add space between `\3A` and scheduleID

Comment: My FormID is "frm_plan" and the scheduleID is "sde_plan" so i add to my css: `frm_plan\:sde_plan th.fc-agenda-axis`. Firebug and Opera doesn't display the schedule anymore and Chrome seems not to understand what i'm defining in my css. It displays the schedule normal. I will add my layout and my schedule page above.

Comment: i forgot to add `#` before the `formID` , try `#frm_plan\:sde_plan th.fc-agenda-axis`

Comment: Thanks, but i mean this: `#frm_plan\:schedule table.fc-agenda-slots` So You can hide the table with all the time slots. `#frm_plan\:schedule table.fc-agenda-axsis`  Thanks a lot for your help. Can you make an answer for other who have the same problems like me?

Comment: By the way, this doesn't work for the M$ IE. I'm will reseach for a solution. (tested with IE9)

Comment: that's why i initial suggested `\3A` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector , does `#formID\3A scheduleID table.fc-agenda-slots` work better ? Also you can add `prependId="false"` to your form , and use `#scheduleID table.fc-agenda-slots`

Comment: Alright, please add to your anwser the IE9 requiered `prependId="false"` and `#scheduleID table.fc-agenda-slots` to get it working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: doesn't `#frm_plan\3A schedule table.fc-agenda-slots` works  for you (without adding `prependId="false"`)?

Comment: `#frm_plan\3A schedule table.fc-agenda-slots` also works. I just have two # of these in my css. ;) Removed one and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just use the basicDay and basicWeek views? Rather than agendaWeek/agendaDay? Those two views don't show the time-slots..... Saves messing around with the CSS etc!

Comment: This is the best answer over all the other ones!

Comment: this should be the answer - why not change the selected answer when we all can see that this is the best solution???

Answer (score 1):

customize the header template it will save you tons of css altering.

```
     <p:schedule id="mySechedule" 
rightHeaderTemplate="month, basicWeek, basicDay" 
value="#{myBean.eventModel}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the *Month*-Button, simply use this Code.

```
<style type="text/css">
.fc-button-month{ display: none; }
</style>
```

For *Week*-Button use CSS Selector `.fc-button-agendaWeek` and for the *Day*-Button: `.fc-button-agendaDay`

Regards!