# How to Override .ui-panelgrid td for specific <p:panelGrid>

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

How do I override a specific `<p:panelGrid>` in my Stylecheet?

In according to this: [How to hide time-slots ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856449/how-to-hide-time-slots-in-agendaweek-view-of-fullcalendar-primefaces-pschedu)

I tried:

```
#frm_dash\3Adisplay td.ui-panelgrid {
    padding:0px 0px;
}
```

and

```
#frm_dash\3Adisplay .ui-panelgrid td {
    padding:0px 0px;
}
```

But it seems not working.

The page is build in this physical structure:

```
<h:form id="frm_dash">
    [...]
    <p:panelGrid id="pnlg_page" style="width: 100%;">
        [...]
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top" colspan="1">

                <p:panelGrid id="display" columns="2"> 
                    [...]
                </p:panelGrid> 

            </p:column>

            <p:column colspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;">
                [...]                                       
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        [...]
    </p:panelGrid>
    [...]
</h:form>
```

Primefaces 3.4.1. - Tomcat 7.x - Mojarra

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202179/primefaces-custom-positioning-for-a-spesific-pgrowl does this apply for your case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made 2 mistakes:

1. The `\3A` must be followed by a blank space.
2. The `.ui-panelgrid` class is been set on the `<table>` itself, not on a child of it.

So, this should do:

```css
#frm_dash\3A display.ui-panelgrid td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Or just this, as it makes no sense to use a classname selector on an element which is already selected by an ID which is by itself supposed to be unique already:

```css
#frm_dash\3A display td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

As a different alternative, give the panel grid a style class so that you can reuse the same appearance on the other elements:

```
<p:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" styleClass="nopadding">
```

with (a more clean CSS selector)

```css
table.nopadding td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to use JSF generated HTML element ID with colon ":" in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878692/how-to-use-jsf-generated-html-element-id-in-css-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

just add a css code

```
.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell{
   padding 0px;
 }
```

- this code if you import your page kill primefaces css