# CSS for all cases with colon in id-selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

this is a question related to a case mentioned here: [Handling a colon in an element ID in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector)

I have some code which contains footnotes which are noted this way `<sup id="fnref:fn1">1</sup>` and `<sup id="fnref:fn2">2</sup>` etc.

In my css I know how to make a rule for each case

```
sub#fnref\:fn1 {vertical-align: super} // or "\3A" instead of ":" to be correct
sub#fnref\:fn2 {vertical-align: super}
```

But how to write the css to get all cases into one rule (I don't want to make a endless list for all potential footnotes.

Thanks in advance
Florian

Answer (score 3):

Use an attribute selector instead:

```
sup[id^="fnref:fn"] {vertical-align: super}
```

By the way you should be selecting `sup` elements and not `sub` elements.

Comment: Using a class would probably be better. Not sure if browsers make use of whatever mapping for IDs to elements they have in case of the attribute selector.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: What do you mean in your second sentence?

Comment: `#id` probably uses a hashtable-like lookup internally. However, for an `[id^='..']` selector that might not work and at least require iteration over all elements that have an ID.

Comment: Ah I understand. I doubt they have mappings for IDs in attribute selectors really, but I'm not too concerned about any effect it would have on performance either. Some browsers do type checks early so it should be easy to first limit it only to `sup` elements in this case before checking their ids.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I'm not free to choose. I get the data in the specified way.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks for your answer! Obviously you're also right with the objection against my selection :-)