# p:inputText within p:layoutUnit does not work inside p:dialog

Tags: css, primefaces

I have a modal dialog that contains some input components.

The problem appears when a p:layout is used inside the dialog. The p:inputText component within a p:layoutUnit can gain focus at the first time, but then it become unresponsive to the keyboard, because no input text is showed, nor I'm able to switch to other input fields using the tab keyword (I can switch to another input component with the mouse only).

Setting modal="false" solve the problem, but I need a modal dialog.

Here is my code:

```
<h:form id="outerForm">
    <p:commandButton id="button" value="Show dialog" onclick="dialogVar.show()" type="button" />

    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="inputText inside p:layout will not work" widgetVar="dialogVar" modal="true" resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true">

            <h:inputText />
            <p:autoComplete />

            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Write something" />
                <p:inputText />
                <h:outputLabel value="Write something else" />
                <p:inputText />
                <h:outputLabel value="Text Area" />
                <p:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="30" autoResize="false" />
            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:layout id="diffDialogLayout" style="height:400px;width:900px;">

                <p:layoutUnit id="diffWestUnit" position="west" size="45%">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Write something" />
                        <p:inputText />
                        <h:outputLabel value="Write something else" />
                        <p:inputText />
                        <h:outputLabel value="Text Area" />
                        <p:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="30" autoResize="false" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="diffCenterUnit" position="center">
                    <br />
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>

            <h:inputText />

    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

My environment:

- PrimeFaces 3.4.2
- PrimeFaces Extensions 0.6.1
- Mojarra 2.1.13
- Tomcat 7.0.30
- Eclipse Indigo SR1

**Edit**

The proposed solution works fine. The problem can be solved with the following CSS code:

```
.ui-dialog { z-index: 1005 !important; }
.ui-layout-pane-west { z-index: 1010 !important; }
.ui-layout-pane-center { z-index: 1010 !important; }
```

or, if you want it for a specific dialog only:

```
#outerForm\3A diffDialog.ui-dialog { z-index: 1005 !important; }
#outerForm\3A diffWestUnit.ui-layout-pane-west { z-index: 1010 !important; }
#outerForm\3A diffCenterUnit.ui-layout-pane-center { z-index: 1010 !important; }
```

The **\3A** character is used for compatibility with IE 6-8, as stated here: [Handling a colon in an element ID in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector).

Comment: not sure , but try adding `appendToBody="true"` to your `p:dialog`

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can able to reproduce your problem, The source of this problem is the `z-index:1003` which is automatically inserted when using `modal=true` attribute in primefaces `<p:dialog>`

you can make a workaround using a small css hack

css:

`.ui-layout-pane-west
{
    z-index:1008 !important; /*any value higher than the modal dialog's z-index */
}`

before using the above css i suggest you to check the z-index of modal panel and change the value accordingly.

**Edit**

Take a look at the following link [Problem with p:layout inside of p:dialog](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13468) at primefaces forum, Taking a closer look at the source of [jQuery Layout and jQuery Dialog](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/layout_inside_dialog.html) of which primefaces components are built, You can see that `dialogLayout_settings = {
            zIndex:             0
}` modal dialog is initialized with `z-index:0`, hence i suggest you to set the `z-index` of `<p:dialog>` to some constant value, like

`.ui-dialog{z-index:1005 !important;}`

however test this with your other components to avoid overlaps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Valuable hack, but the z-index value is not always the same. If you update the page, the z-index of the modal dialog increases each time. Furthermore, only input component inside a layout component are affected.

Comment: can you explain, what other components are causing the problem??

Comment: In my code example, the dialog contains some input components, and _only the ones inside the layout_ don't work, due to the z-index issue you pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for the links (I searched the PrimeFaces forum before posting here, but I missed that post). I'll try your suggestion about the ui-dialog style.