# How do you call an id in css that has a leading colon? (note: backslash doesn't work)

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling a colon in an element ID in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector)

I'm playing around with Gmail's CSS using Minimalist for Everything (otherwise i'd just change the element's id), and some of the elements are named with leading colons.

E.g., the settings button's element id is #:pd

Looking it up if it were in the middle of the word a : should work fine, but have seen a few sources that say that it leading with a colon should be *impossible*...but its definitely the id name's leading character (see also the screenshot).

— — — — 
Edit: This isn't a duplicate because I'm asking about the case where the id begins with a colon, in which case the backslash doesn't seem to work. See the following [screenshot](http://note.io/13CFpms) to see what I mean. I tried escaping the backslash itself followed by the

Comment: well why do use `:` in id or class name ?

Comment: I didn't have a choice. It was a gmail quirky id name.

Answer (score 0):

Using the backslash in your CSS (i.e. #:pa) works just fine, at least in WebKit (I didn't test others).

Relevant:

- [Handling a colon in an element ID in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762307(VS.85).aspx