# CSS selector with doublepoint?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

how can i select div?

```
<div id="languageForm:j_id427:0:j_id432">Test</div>
```

this code does not work

```
#languageForm:j_id427:0:j_id432 { color:#00aa00; }
```

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:` is a special character in CSS (`:hover`)

Use `\00003A` to escape it:

```
#languageForm\00003Aj_id427\00003A0\00003Aj_id432 { color:#00aa00; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QeSzV/)

Note: Don't use `\:` because it [doesn't work in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector).

Why the many `0`s? Because the browser will try to read at most 6 characters to parse a unicode constant in CSS files. Without the zeros, it would read `\3Aj` and stop with an error.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector contains `:` so you need to escape them using a backslash `\`, use this

```
#languageForm\:j_id427\:0\:j_id432 { 
     color:#00aa00; 
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/73sPp/)

> Note: May be older browsers will fail in escaping, in this case you
>   can use \3a which is colon equivalent.

```
#languageForm\3a j_id427\3a 0\3a j_id432 { 
    color:#00aa00; 
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/73sPp/1/) (Note the spaces after `\3a`)

(Consider referring [aarons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17672129/1542290) if you are going with (`\3A`) solution)

Comment: Note: This doesn't work in IE7.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I was just creating a fiddle with `\3a` :)

Comment: I don't like the space after the Unicode escape; it messes with the syntax highlighting of almost any CSS editor.

Comment: @AaronDigulla yea its kinda confusing but i went for the shorter syntax :)

Comment: `\3a\j...`  works (i.e. use a `\ ` instead of a space) but you'd have to use `\30` instead of `\0` which would be confusing as well.

Comment: @AaronDigulla oh ok, thanks a lot, that was something new for me :)