# How to convert complex xpath to css

Tags: css, xpath

I have a complex html structure. New to CSS. Want to change my xpath to css as there could be some performance impact in IE

Xpath by firebug: `.//*[@id='T_I:3']/span/a`

I finetuned to : `//div[@id='Overview']/descendant::*[@id='T_I:3']/span/a`

Now I need corresponding CSS for the same. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think your "finetuning" did the best possible job. An element `id` should be unique in the document and is therefore usually cached by modern browsers (which means that id lookup is instant). You can help the XPath engine by using the [`id()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id) function.

Therefore, the XPath expression would be: `id('T_I:3')/span/a` (yes, that's a valid XPath 1.0 expression).

Anyway, to convert this to CSS, you'd use: `#T_I:3 > span > a`

Your "finetuned" expression converted would be: `div#Overview #T_I:3 > span > a`, but seriously, you only need one `id` selection.

[The hashtag `#` is an `id` selector.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors)

[The space () is a descendant combinator.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)

[The `>` sign is a child combinator.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)

---

**EDIT** based on a good comment by Fréderic Hamidi:

> I don't think `#T_I:3` is valid (the colon would be confused with the
>   start of a pseudo-class). You would have to find a way to escape it.

It turns out you also need to escape the underscore. For this, use the techniques mentioned in this SO question: [Handling a colon in an element ID in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector).

The final CSS selector would be:

```
#T\5FI\3A3 > span > a
```

Comment: I don't think `#T_I:3` is valid (the colon would be confused with the start of a pseudo-class). You would have to find a way to escape it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Wow. I have been working with XPath and CSS for like five years and I haven't bumped into this. Thank you for learning me something new today!

Comment: Thanks Slanec and Frederic. Your inputs are so useful

Comment: One more small doubt if the id = Refresh--  is same on both div left and right; please suggest on how to deal with it      //div[@id='Overview_Left']/descendant::input[@id='Refresh']

Comment: @user2742533 That's a clear error in the markup, it's against the spec and should be repaired. If you can't access it, you'll have to stick to your finetuned version for which I provided a conversion to a CSS selector, too. Just don't forget to escape all the needed characters.

Comment: 65535-123 > td:nth-of-type(9) > a
css selectors should not start with numbers. 65535-123 is an id. I used the below one but it didnt work
\65535\-123 > td:nth-of-type(9) > span

Comment: And I tried the following by including division above it also -- div#One #65535\-123 > td:nth-of-type(9) > span