# Dealing with a colon in BeautifulSoup CSS selectors

Tags: python, html, css-selectors, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

**Input HTML:**

```
<div style="display: flex">
    <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;width: 33%;"> apple </div>
    <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;text-align: center;width: 28%;"> peach </div>
    <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;text-align: right;width: 33%;" title="nofruit"> cucumber </div>
</div>
```

**The desired output:** all `div` elements exactly under `<div style="display: flex">`.

I'm trying to locate the parent `div` with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
div[style="display: flex"]
```

This throws an error:

```
>>> soup.select('div[style="display: flex"]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1400, in select
    'Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.')
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.
```

It looks like `BeautifulSoup` tries to interpret the colon as a pseudo-class syntax.

I've tried to follow the advices suggested at [Handling a colon in an element ID in a CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector), but it still throws errors:

```
>>> soup.select('div[style="display\: flex"]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1400, in select
    'Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.')
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.
>>> soup.select('div[style="display\3A flex"]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1426, in select
    'Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token)
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "div[style="displayA"
```

**The Question:**

What is the correct way to use/escape a colon in attribute values in `BeautifulSoup` CSS selectors?

---

Note that I can workaround it with a partial attribute match:

```
soup.select("div[style$=flex]")
```

Or, with a [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
soup.find_all("div", style="display: flex")
```

Also note that I understand that using `style` to locate elements is far from being a good location technique, but the question itself is meant to be generic and the provided HTML is just an example.

Comment: I assume you have also tried two backslashes? `soup.select('div[style="display\\: flex"]')`

Comment: @JoshCrozier happy new year, yup, and different combinations with raw strings and regular strings. Thanks. Still think I'm just missing smth.

Comment: ... wat. Talk about broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update:* the issue is now fixed in BeautifulSoup 4.5.0, upgrade if needed:

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

---

Old answer:

Created an issue at the `BeautifulSoup` issue tracker:

- [Dealing with a colon in BeautifulSoup CSS selectors](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1540588)

Will update the answer in case of any updates in the launchpad issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this constitutes an *answer* exactly, as it is most definitely broken. However, strangely the error is triggered not by the `:` itself, but by the `:` followed by a space. The error suggests it's trying to use whatever is after the space as a CSS selector.

For example, editing the HTML to drop the space makes the block selectable again:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """
... <div style="display:flex">
...     <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;width: 33%;"> apple </div>
...     <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;text-align: center;width: 28%;"> peach </div>
...     <div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;text-align: right;width: 33%;" title="nofruit"> cucumber </div>
... </div>
... """

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.select('div[style="display: flex"]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1313, in select
    'Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "%s"' % token)
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "flex"]"

>>> soup.select('div[style="display:flex"]')
[<div style="display:flex">
<div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;width: 33%;"> apple </div>
<div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;text-align: center;width: 28%;"> peach </div>
<div class="half" style="font-size: 0.8em;text-align: right;width: 33%;" title="nofruit"> cucumber </div>
</div>]
```

Unfortunately, with the space is the usual style so this probably won't get you very far at all!

Comment: Interesting observation! Thanks.