# Using BeautifulSoup to find tag with two specific styles

Tags: python, html, css, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use the BeautifulSoup (bs4) package in Python2.7 to find the following tag in an html document:

```
<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:408px; top:540px; width:14px; height:9px;"><span style="font-family: OEULZL+ArialMT; font-size:9px">0.00<br></span></div>
```

In the html document there are multiple other tags that are almost exactly identical - the only consistently difference is the "left:408px" and the "height:9px" attributes.

How can i find this tag using `BeautifulSoup`?

Ive tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs("<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:408px; top:540px; width:14px; height:9px;"><span style="font-family: OEULZL+ArialMT; font-size:9px">0.00<br></span></div>", 'html.parser')

soup.find_all('div', style=('left:408px' and 'height:9px'))
soup.find_all('div', style=('left:408px') and style=('height:9px')) #doesn't like style being used twice
soup.find_all('div', {'left':'408px' and 'height':'9px'})
soup.find_all('div', {'left:408px'} and {'height:9px'})
soup.find_all('div', style={'left':'408px' and 'height':'9px'})
soup.find_all('div', style={'left:408px'} and {'height:9px'})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check the `style` to have `left:408px` and `height:9px` inside it:

```
soup.find('div', style=lambda value: value and 'left:408px' in value and 'height:9px' in value)
```

Or:

```
import re
soup.find('div', style=re.compile(r'left:408px.*?height:9px'))
```

Or:

```
soup.select_one('div[style*="408px"]')
```

Note that, in general, *style properties are not reliable to use for locating elements*. See if there is anything else - check the parent, sibling elements, or may be there is a corresponding label near the element.

Note that, a more appropriate CSS selector would be `div[style*="left:408px"][style*="height:9px"]`, but because of the [limited CSS selector support](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553622/dealing-with-a-colon-in-beautifulsoup-css-selectors), it is not gonna work as is.

Comment: Thanks! I like the regex option.  Unfortunately i'm stuck solely with css style elements.