# Searching for a text that contains a particular text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

From the following html,

```
html = '''
<td>the keyword is present in the <a href='text' title='text'>text</a> </td>
<td>word key is not present</td>
<td>no keyword here</td>'''
```

I want to find the strings that that the word "keyword" them.

So in this example, I want to find

```
<td>the keyword is present in the <a href='text' title='text'>text</a> </td>
<td>no keyword here</td>
```

So I tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
ans = soup.find_all('td', text=lambda l: l and 'keyword' in l)
print(ans)
# [<td>no keyword here</td>]
```

But this doesn't return the other line that has "keyword" in it. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<td>the keyword is present in the <a href='text' title='text'>text</a> </td>
<td>word key is not present</td>
<td>no keyword here</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
print(*[td for td in soup.find_all("td") if 'keyword' in td.text], sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
<td>the keyword is present in the <a href="text" title="text">text</a> </td>
<td>no keyword here</td>
```

You can use `td.text` for get text in `<td>` like below:

```
print(*[td.text for td in soup.find_all("td") if 'keyword' in td.text], sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
the keyword is present in the text 
no keyword here
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `:contains` with [`CSS Selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
html = '''
<td>the keyword is present in the <a href='text' title='text'>text</a> </td>
<td>word key is not present</td>
<td>no keyword here</td>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.select('td:contains("keyword")'))

>>> [<td>the keyword is present in the <a href="text" title="text">text</a> </td>, 
    <td>no keyword here</td>]
```

**EDIT**

With new version of BS4 `:contains` has been deprecated, You can try using [`-soup:contains()`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains) or [`-soup:contains-own()`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains-own).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = """<table><tr>
<td>the keyword is present in the <a href='text' title='text'>text</a> </td>
<td>word key is not present</td>
<td>no keyword here</td>
</table>"""
soup = bs(html)
variable = "keyword"
print(soup.select(f'td:-soup-contains({variable})'.format(variable)))
```

The above `variable` can be passed through command line ([`Reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001892/reading-named-command-arguments)).

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--keyword', help='Add some keyword to search')
args=parser.parse_args()
keyword = args.keyword
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = """<table><tr>
<td>the keyword is present in the <a href='text' title='text'>text</a> </td>
<td>word key is not present</td>
<td>no keyword here</td></tr>
</table>"""
soup = bs(html,'html5lib')
print(soup.select(f'td:-soup-contains({keyword})'))
```

Comment: say, soup.select is in a function and "keyword" has to come from an argument, how do we do the same job? e.g.  html = '''
<p>the keyword string is present in the <a href='text'>text</a> </p>
<p>the_word is here</p>'''
the_word = 'keyword string'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.select('p:contains(the_word)'))
# it prints [<td>the_word is here</td>] when we wanted [<p>the keyword string is present in the <a href='text'>text</a></p>]

Comment: I'm getting NotImplementedError. Does it mean BeautifulSoup on my machine is not up to date?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553622/dealing-with-a-colon-in-beautifulsoup-css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by something like?

```py
html = '''
<td>the keyword is present in the <a href='text' title='text'>text</a> </td>
<td>word key is not present</td>
<td>no keyword here</td>'''
print('\n'.join(line for line in html.splitlines() if 'keyword' in line))
```

Output:

```
<td>the keyword is present in the <a href='text' title='text'>text</a> </td>
<td>no keyword here</td>
```