# Use of separators with special characters for CSS name selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, special-characters

**How accurate is the use of special characters in css names, as in tailwind css framework?**

I mean, I like it very much and I want to use it. I did some research. Either most of the sources did not say anything, or the source connections were broken.

### Actually,

```css
.hover\:red:hover
{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="hover:red">Dummy (Hover me)</p>
```

Is it true that using this will work properly on all devices and third party browsers, except IE8 and below browsers?

Finally, is there a disadvantage for search engines? So `SEO`, `usability`, `accessibility` etc.

Comment: `How accurate` is a vague way to ask a question.  You best be might be trial and error across the spectrum of possibilities.

Comment: also look at this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short **YES**

As you can see [Tailwind Browser Support](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/browser-support) they cover all major browsers including IE 11.

Also they support [accessibility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screen-readers) as well with same approach.

So I don't think there is harm in this approach and any search engine will throw an error because its valid CSS selector. You can test it on [w3c validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). Also there is no open SEO related issue on their [Github Repo](https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues). So I believe you can feel free to use this approach.

BTW I just know about this selector lol.