# Playwright Locator .getbyid

Tags: playwright

I have a text field on my website with the ID:'pageContentForm:username'

I'm trying to fill this field with 'myusername:
await page.locator("#pageContentForm:username").fill('myusername');

Unfortunately that doesn't work. I can't find anywhere how to address a web object with the ID.

Comment: Please share the page you're manipulating and a runnable, complete [mcve] of your code. By "doesn't" work, do you mean there's an error? If so, which one? If not, how do you know it's not working? If the problem is the colon in the id, then see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/handling-a-colon-in-an-element-id-in-a-css-selector). Thanks.

Comment: Does your id have really  a colon in between? Does your node really look like ```<input id="pageContentForm:username"...>``` ? That´s very strange. I guess your node is ```<input id="username">``` . If yes you have to use ```locator('#username').fill('my_username')```. You can use ```F12``` of your browser and investigate your DOM and by using ```Ctrl+Shirft+C``` inspect the node

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you highlight the object in dev tools in browser?

Answer (score 1):

In some frameworks, a colon in the ID can be common
E.g. in JSF, IDs of inputs have the ID of the containing form.

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="myForm:myInput">
</form>
```

What you can do, is to use an XPath expression as your selector:

```
page.locator('[id="pageContentForm:username"]').fill('myusername');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working. Thanks

```
const USERID=page.locator('[id="pageContentForm:username"]')
const PWD=page.locator('[id="pageContentForm:suffix"]')
```